# How can I test DELETE api in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, codeception

How can I test RESTful api of DELETE in Laravel by using Codeception?

I use the following function:

```php
    public function authenticatedUserSuccessDeleteEmployee(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantToTest('authenticated super user success delete employee');
        // set header authorization
        $I->amBearerAuthenticated($this->token);
        //
        $this->employee = factory(\App\Models\Employee::class)->create([
            'id' => '20200100000000'
        ]);        
        // see database row is containing our expected data
        $I->seeRecord('employees', ['id' => '20200100000000']);
        // Send delete request
        $I->sendDELETE('employees', array('id' => '20200100000000'));
        // check expected response code is 200 OK
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
    }
```

But the employee does not created in the DB!

How can I create an object for testing delete API?

Comment: Short answer is "YES"

Comment: if you are using phpunit , you can make an integration test , so first , you need to create the object in the DB . and then call your api endoint (for example  by object id). after that , you have to query your database with the same id that was created in the first step and deleted by your api . the result should be an empty which make you sure that the endpoint has really delete the object

Comment: The problem is this test will fail!
And the error is `The requested resource was not found.` Which means the object was not created in the DB.

Comment: Also I want to use `Codeception`. I am looking for an example for testing DELETE api in Laravel by using `Codeception`. For example here I found something for testing create: https://medium.com/teknomuslim/automated-api-testing-laravel-using-jwt-and-codeception-6c587516fea6 But couldn't find any example for testing DELETE api.

Comment: Why do `$id = $this->getExpectedId()` if you hardcode the id in the `seeRecord?

Comment: @apokryfos: I modified my code be able to publish it here. I forgot to remove that function also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I need to send the id as part of the url!

```
$I->sendDELETE('employees/20200100000000');
```